# Creating a simple lexical analyser in Java

Tags: java, lexical

I am creating a lexical analyser that must read a text input and output tokens for a basic 'created' language and should output a token when called. I would like it to distinguish between identifiers, constants etc.. from a list of which I pre-determine.

I need to read the text file using an input stream. A while loop will loop through chars individually but I need it to recognise if the chars scanned are an identifier or a '+' '-' '*' '/' etc... what would be the best way to do this?

I am fairly new to programming so any advice on how to construct this would be appreciated.
many thanks for any answers

Answer (score 4):

Do not try to write your own lexer / parser.

It is easier to use a lexer/parser generator like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org) or [SableCC](http://sablecc.org/).

Answer (score 2):

The [`StreamTokenizer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html) class will probably help you out the most.  It will read and distinguish between identifiers, numbers, and strings.  You can also configure it to identify operators, such as `+`, `*`, etc.

Comment: +1 for good ol' `StreamTokenizer`. There's an example [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/enumerated-functions).